# How to export all constants at once?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file where I export constants.

```
export const PASSWORD_MISMATCH_ERROR = 'Passwords not match!';
export const USER_NOT_FOUND_ERROR = 'User not found';
export const WRONG_PASSWORD_ERROR = 'The password is incorrect';
export const UNAUTHORIZED = 'User unauthorized';
```

How do I make it so that I don't have to export each constant separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ECMAScript 262 specification allows this trivially](http://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#sec-exports):

```
export const
    PASSWORD_MISMATCH_ERROR = 'Passwords not match!',
    USER_NOT_FOUND_ERROR = 'User not found',
    WRONG_PASSWORD_ERROR = 'The password is incorrect',
    UNAUTHORIZED = 'User unauthorized';
```

Comment: @user20328528 I've edited the answer to illustrate what I'd recommend as the idiomatic solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can export them all as a config together:

```js
export const ERRORS = {
  PASSWORD_MISMATCH_ERROR: 'Passwords not match!',
  USER_NOT_FOUND_ERROR: 'User not found',
  WRONG_PASSWORD_ERROR: 'The password is incorrect',
  UNAUTHORIZED: 'User unauthorized',
}
```

Now, when you add some new variable, you don't have to explicitly export it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `module.exports`

```
const PASSWORD_MISMATCH_ERROR = 'Passwords not match!';
const USER_NOT_FOUND_ERROR = 'User not found';
const WRONG_PASSWORD_ERROR = 'The password is incorrect';
const UNAUTHORIZED = 'User unauthorized';
module.exports = {
 PASSWORD_MISMATCH_ERROR,
 USER_NOT_FOUND_ERROR, 
 WRONG_PASSWORD_ERROR,
 UNAUTHORIZED
}
```

and then in the file where you want to import, you can either using  normal way or by object destructuring.

```
const constants = require('path to the file');
```

and access it like `constants.UNAUTHORIZED`

**OR**

```
const {PASSWORD_MISMATCH_ERROR, USER_NOT_FOUND_ERROR, WRONG_PASSWORD_ERROR, UNAUTHORIZED } = require('path to the file');
```

Comment: Note that your answer is using the common JS (CJS) way of exporting/importing and not the EcmaScript Modules (ESM) way of exporting/importing. From OPs question, they are using ESM, not CJS (so this won't work)